# JSON menu with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to create a menu width jquery and JSON. But I cant figure out how to tie the submenus to their parents. I have used this dummy data in a json file:

```
{"menu":[
{"name": "Croatia", "link": "#", "sub": null
},
{"name": "England", "link": "#", "sub": [
    {"name": "Arsenal","link": "#", "sub": null},
    {"name": "Liverpool","link": "#", "sub": null},
    {"name": "Manchester United","link": "#", "sub": null}
    ]},
{"name": "Spain", "link": "#", "sub": [
    {"name": "Barcelona","link": "#", "sub": null},
    {"name": "Real Madrid","link": "#", "sub": null}
]},        
{"name": "Germany", "link": "#","sub": [
    {"name": "Bayern Munich","link": "#", "sub": null},
    {"name": "Borrusia Dortmund","link": "#", "sub": null}
    ]}
]}
```

And this is the closest i have been to a working solution:

```
$.getJSON( "json/menu.json", function( data ) {
    $("#menu").append("<nav><ul class='depth-0'></ul></nav>")
    $.each( data.menu, function( key, val ) {
      var li = "<li id=" + key + ">" + val.name + "</li>";
      $("#menu nav ul.depth-0").append(li);
      if(val.sub != null){
        $("<ul class='depth-1'></ul>").appendTo( $("li#" + key + "") );
        $.each( val.sub, function(key,sub){
            $("#menu nav ul.depth-1").append("<li>" + sub.name + "</li>");
        });
      }
    });
}).error(function() { alert("error"); });
```

But I need some kind of this-statement because this of course appends the li to all depth-1 ul's:

```
Croatia
England
  Arsenal
  Liverpool
  Manchester United
  Barcelona
  Real Madrid
  Bayern Munich
  Borrusia Dortmund
Spain
  Barcelona
  Real Madrid
  Bayern Munich
  Borrusia Dortmund
Germany
  Bayern Munich
  Borrusia Dortmund
```

Can anybody help me with a solution to this, and also if it is possible to append the depth-1 ul to the current var li instead of using the id+key as selector, that would be a better solution, but i couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your problem?

Comment: I have tried, but the fiddle gives me an error on loading the json. Is it not possible to load external json into a fiddle?

Comment: Yes you can in the `External Resources` but it is easier just to add a variable with the value of your json.

Comment: It is time you took a look at a template engine. Plenty of options: a very lightweight: https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates

Comment: I know, this will not be helpful, but I have to do it: it is "Borussia Dortmund", 1 r and 2 s. Now I feel better ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to use jQuery objects and append the data to them. You need to change the logic a little

```
$("#menu").append("<nav><ul class='depth-0'></ul></nav>"); 

$.each(data.menu, function (key, val) {

    var li = $("<li>", {   // create li element (a.k.a parent li)
        id: 'li' + key,    // the ID should not be only numbers 
        text: val.name
    });

    if (val.sub != null) {    // if li has children 

        var ul = $("<ul>", {  // create ul element
            class: 'depth-1'
        });

        $.each(val.sub, function (key, sub) {
            ul.append("<li>" + sub.name + "</li>");  // append children to ul
        });

        ul.appendTo(li);    // append ul to parent li
    }

    li.appendTo('#menu nav ul.depth-0'); // append parent li to main ul.depth-0

});
```

We can take it even further and append it only when it's completely finished

```
var ul_main = $("<ul class='depth-0'></ul>");

$.each(data.menu, function (key, val) {
    var li = $("<li>", { id: 'li' + key, text: val.name });
    if (val.sub != null) {
        var ul = $("<ul>", { class: 'depth-1' });

        $.each(val.sub, function (key, sub) {
            ul.append("<li>" + sub.name + "</li>");
        });

        ul.appendTo(li);
    }
    li.appendTo(ul_main);
});

$("<nav></nav>").append(ul_main).appendTo('#menu');
```

```js
var data = {
    "menu": [{
        "name": "Croatia",
            "link": "#",
            "sub": null
    }, {
        "name": "England",
            "link": "#",
            "sub": [{
            "name": "Arsenal",
                "link": "#",
                "sub": null
        }, {
            "name": "Liverpool",
                "link": "#",
                "sub": null
        }, {
            "name": "Manchester United",
                "link": "#",
                "sub": null
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Spain",
            "link": "#",
            "sub": [{
            "name": "Barcelona",
                "link": "#",
                "sub": null
        }, {
            "name": "Real Madrid",
                "link": "#",
                "sub": null
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Germany",
            "link": "#",
            "sub": [{
            "name": "Bayern Munich",
                "link": "#",
                "sub": null
        }, {
            "name": "Borrusia Dortmund",
                "link": "#",
                "sub": null
        }]
    }]
}

$("#menu").append("<nav><ul class='depth-0'></ul></nav>");

$.each(data.menu, function (key, val) {
    var li = $("<li>", {
        id: key,
        text: val.name
    });
    if (val.sub != null) {
        var ul = $("<ul>", {
            class: 'depth-1'
        });
        $.each(val.sub, function (key, sub) {
            ul.append("<li>" + sub.name + "</li>");
        });
        ul.appendTo(li);
    }
    li.appendTo('#menu nav ul.depth-0');
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='menu'></div>
```

Comment: Amazing.. looks like it worked like a charm. Could you point me toward the right direction if I later on want to add an active class to the active li? I guess it should be incorporated into this code somehow.

Comment: I guess, if it's in the JSON you simply have to check for it and add it. If you struggle with it you can always ask a new question :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if this code is helpful.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

str_json='{"menu":[{"name": "Croatia", "link": "#", "sub": null},{"name": "England", "link": "#",   "sub": [{"name": "Arsenal","link": "#", "sub": null},    {"name": "Liverpool","link": "#", "sub": null},    {"name": "Manchester United","link": "#", "sub": null}    ]},{"name": "Spain", "link": "#", "sub": [    {"name": "Barcelona","link": "#", "sub": null},    {"name": "Real Madrid","link": "#", "sub": null}]}, {"name": "Germany", "link": "#","sub": [    {"name": "Bayern Munich","link": "#", "sub": null},    {"name": "Borrusia Dortmund","link": "#", "sub": null}  ]}]}';


data_json=$.parseJSON(str_json);


var html_string='<nav><ul class="depth-0">';
for(i=0;i<data_json.menu.length;i++)
{
    html_string=html_string+'<li> <span class="parent"> <a href="'+data_json.menu[i].link+'"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>'+data_json.menu[i].name+'</a></span><ul>';

    if(data_json.menu[i].sub!=null)
    {
        for(j=0;j<data_json.menu[i].sub.length;j++)
        {
            html_string=html_string+'<li><a href="'+data_json.menu[i].sub[j].link+'" class="tree-links">'+data_json.menu[i].sub[j].name+'</a></li>';
        }
    }
    html_string=html_string+'</ul></li>';                   
}
html_string=html_string+'</ul></nav>';

$("#menu").append(html_string);

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu"></div>
</body>
</html>
```